# Como actualizar el valor de las variables de TimelineMax en el evento window.resize?

Tags: jquery, scroll

Estoy desarrollando una web con scroll vertical y horizontal. Me gustaría desplazarme horizontalmente cuando bajo la rueda del mouse. **Lo he logrado con ScrollMagic y GSAP (TimelineMax).**

Pero cuando cambio el tamaño de la ventana (window.resize), necesito actualizar las variables que contienen la cantidad de píxeles que tengo que desplazar hacia la derecha o izquierda.

Cuando se carga la web, hago una serie de cálculos para saber cuántos píxeles tengo que desplazar hacia la derecha (var amount_to_scroll):

```
function calculateCarruselDimensions() {
    var total_width = 0;
    var total_global_width = 0;
    var amount_to_scroll = 0;

    $('.carrusel').find('.carrusel_item').each(function() {
        _this = $(this);
        _this.css('width', _this.find('img').width() + 'px');
        console.log(_this.find('img').width());
        total_width += _this.find('img').width();
        //console.log( _this.attr('id') + '=' + total_width );
    });

    total_global_width = total_width;
    $('.carrusel').find('.panel').css('width', total_global_width + 'px');
    amount_to_scroll = total_global_width - $(window).width();

    return amount_to_scroll;
}

$(window).on("load", function() {
    if ($('.carrusel').length) {
        var controller = new ScrollMagic.Controller();
        var horizontalSlide = new TimelineMax();

        $('.carrusel').imagesLoaded(function() {

            amount_to_scroll = calculateCarruselDimensions();
            console.log(amount_to_scroll);

            horizontalSlide.fromTo("#slideContainer", 10,
            {
                x: "0"
            }, {
                x: amount_to_scroll * (-1) + 'px',
                ease: Linear.easeNone,
            });

            scene = new ScrollMagic.Scene({
                triggerElement: "#slideWrapper",
                triggerHook: "onLeave",
                duration: amount_to_scroll + 'px' }).
            setPin("#slideWrapper").
            setTween(horizontalSlide).
            addTo(controller);
        });
    }
});
```

Ahora, cuando el tamaño de la ventana cambia, he hecho esto:

```
$(window).bind("resize", function() {
    amount_to_scroll = calculateCarruselDimensions();
    //console.log(amount_to_scroll);
    scene.duration(amount_to_scroll + 'px');
});
```

Actualizo la variable scene de ScrollMagic, pero también necesito actualizar la coordenada x de la variable horizontalSlide (TimelineMax.fromTo). Concretamente, esta línea de código:

```
x: amount_to_scroll * (-1) + 'px',
```

**Aquí tenéis el código funcionando en un Pen ([enlace](https://codepen.io/hormigaz22/pen/VwZWWZr))**

No tengo idea de cómo puedo lograrlo. He buscado en internet, pero no he encontrado nada :(

¿Alguien puede mostrarme el camino, por favor?

¡¡Gracias!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finalmente, me han dado la solución en los foros de GreenSock.

Publico aquí el enlace por si alguien tiene un problema similar al mío en el futuro.

**SOLUCIÓN: [enlace a los foros de GreenSock](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/21215-on-window-resize-update-tween-vars-with-new-value/?do=findComment&comment=99893)**

Básicamente lo que hay que hacer es destruir la escena y volverla a crear en el evento 'resize' e integrar el tween dentro de la escena.